# CRONTAB on MAC --> ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:

Tags: python, pandas, cron

After years of reading upon questions and all of your help here on Stack I am now officially a member :)

I am building a script using pandas (for data handling) and want to export this data to excel using df.to_excel(writer) using pd.ExcelWriter.

Scheduling raw python jobs with CronTab is all going fine, tested using * * * * * so the output from the open('x.csv', 'w') as file.... all worked ok.

My Python version is 3.9.7 and the Numpy is 1.21.2

The problem arises when I use the CronTab scheduler on a python script using Pandas and the mail says:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in 
import pandas as pd
File "/Users/*THIS IS ME*/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 16, in 
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy:
IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.
We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.8 from "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
- The NumPy version is: "1.21.2"
  and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
  Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.***

Comment: what is the cron entry that you try to run - share it please,